# Kendo Gantt: Hooking the task template to MVVM

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-gantt

I've been in pursuit of a way, however hacky, to connect the Gantt diagram's task template to a ObservableObject to take advantage of the MVVM system. I am aware that the edit template support this out of the box, however I've been struggling to make it work with the *task template* as well.

Thanks to Josh Eastburn and [his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeastburn/5MU4r/), I found that the *detail template* in the Kendo Grid could be bound to a MVVM through the hooking function `detailInit`.

```
$("#a-kendo-grid").kendoGrid({
    detailTemplate: kendo.template( $("#detail-template").html() ),
    detailInit: function(e) {
        kendo.bind(e.detailRow, e.data); // this line produces the binding
    }
})
```

I tried, optimistically, to alter the parameter names to refer to a task rather than a detail template when instantiating the Kendo Gantt, but it does not seem to have been implemented.

Have anyone come across another hack/trick to bind the Gantt chart's *task template* to MVVMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in contact with Telerik Support. They state that they've not planned to implement a MVVM connection between a Gantt Task and its representative the task template in the timeline interface.

However, I found a hacky way to create a MVVM binding:

HTML

```
<div id="gantt"></div>
<script id="task-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        </div>
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#gantt").kendoGantt({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  taskTemplate: $("#task-template").html(),
  dataBound: function(e) {
    var htmlElement = null;

    e.sender.dataSource.taskTree().forEach(function( taskObject ){
      htmlElement = $(".k-task[data-uid="+taskObject.uid+"]");

      if( htmlElement.find("[data-bind]").get(0).kendoBindingTarget === undefined ){
        // bind unless previously bound
        kendo.bind( htmlElement, taskObject );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This snippet will hook the rendered task template elements in DOM to its representative Task object, after the Gantt Diagram has been bound to new data. This event triggers eg: post the first loading of data, and everytime the users saves an alteration to the Gantt tasks.